# How to search and replace words in ssh?

Tags: search, ssh

I need to change more than 200 words like ( good ) to ( best ) in all files on my hosting.
I have SSH access.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to Magento. It may be a good fit for https://unix.stackexchange.com/ instead